# Best way to compare an iterator values and an enum for matching values in java

Tags: java

I have an iterator that loops through a values with a simple hasNext() function. I also have an enum that contains certain values. I would like to find all the matching values between the enum and the iterator.

I'm trying to do this hopefully with the best performance both runtime and space wise.
Thanks.

For reference to code (it's a simple straightforward case but feel free to ask for more code:

```
Iterator iterator = user.userTasks.iterator(); //loops through current users tasks
        while(iterator.hasNext()) {
            UserTask userTask = (userTask)iterator.next();
            //want to compare userTask above with values from a java enum for any matches
```

The enum has a string field and that is what I'm trying to match to this iterators field too. So, a field of the iterator to a field of the enum.

Comment: What is `UserTask`? Is that the enum you're talking about or does it just have a *field* that is of the enum type? More generally: what's its connection to the enum?

Comment: Show us the code of UserTask and the enum object

Comment: UserTask is extremely long, but it has a field that is a string, and the enum also has a field that is a string. So to be clear, I'm trying to match two fields that are both strings. I will update the question with the enum code. @JoachimSauer

Comment: @Jack_Frost You need to include a shortened version of UserTask which only contains the relevant parts, same for the enum. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your description, you need to match the enum field with and Iterator field.

First lets create an ENUM with a String field.

```java
public enum ExampleEnum {
    
    ONE("one"),
    TWO("two"),
    THREE("three"),
    FOUR("four");
    
    private String eName;
     
    ExampleEnum(String eName) {
        this.eName = eName;
    }
    
    public String geteName(){
        return eName;
    }
    
    public static Stream<ExampleEnum> stream() {
        return Stream.of(ExampleEnum.values()); 
    }
}
```

Use a simple ArrayList as an Iterator in your case replace it with UserTask Iterator.

```java
String[] arr = {"one", "five", "six", "three", "eleven", "two", "four"};
List<String> arrayList = Arrays.asList(arr);
Iterator<String> iterator = arrayList.iterator();

while(iterator.hasNext()){
    String compare = iterator.next();
    ExampleEnum.stream()
    .filter(d -> d.geteName().equals(compare))
    .forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

I'm using Java 8, I guess in Java 9 can be done more easily.